# Delphi XE7 Indy idHTTP client post error authorising

Tags: api, delphi, authorization, indy, idhttp

I'm attempting to connect to an online API using Indy HTTP client.  The error I'm getting is "Authorisation failed (that's our message) EIdOSSLUnderlyingcryptoerror Error connecting with SSL, error:14094410: ssl ROUTINES:SSL3_READ_BYTES:SSLV3 alert handshake failure."

The idSSLIOHandler is set with the mode as sslmClient.

```
`procedure TOnLineSettingsForm.Button5Click(Sender : TObject);
var
S: TStringStream;
R : TStringStream;
sTest : String;
sResponse : String;
sAuthCode : AnsiString;
begin
//S := TStringList.Create;
R := TStringStream.Create;
if Length(edCert.Text) <> 0 then
begin
   try
     try
        sAuthCode := 'AUTHORISATION:' + edCert.Text;
        S := TStringStream.Create('AUTHORISATION:' + edCert.Text,   TEncoding.UTF8);
        S.Position := 0;
        with IdHTTP1 do
        begin
           IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
           Post('https://api.cloudwaitress.com/V1/...', S); //  sAuthCode);
           sResponse := ResponseText;
        end;
        sTest := R.DataString;
     except
        on e:exception do
        begin
           Showmessage('Authorisation failed....' + e.ClassName + ' ' + e.Message);
           sTest := R.DataString;
        end;
     end;
  finally
     s.Free;
     R.Free;
  end;
end else
begin
   Beep;
  Beep;
  ShowMessage('Please enter the id code.');
end;
end;`
```

The documentation says the folowing is required for authentication

curl https://api.cloudwaitress.com/v1/...
  -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY"

I was concerned that the "..." at the end of the url would be invalid, so I left it out. Got the error so put it back. Same error.  So, I suspect, the problem is with something else. I note the authorisation doesn't include anything about content type.  Although other requests for this API do and require "application/json".

Is it possible a handshake failure simply means the API connection isan't valid?

Sorry - should have said - the Indy version is 10.6.1.5182.  I note that the same error can be triggered if TLS is required on the server.  And that Indy 10.6.2 fixed that problem.  Could it be I nned to get a more recent version of Indy?

Thanks

Alan

Comment: `...` should be replaced with API method you want to execute.

Comment: I suspected that may be the case.  And tried it.  No change.  Identical result.  I'm beginning to think there is something wrong with the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> The error I'm getting is "Authorisation failed (that's our message) EIdOSSLUnderlyingcryptoerror Error connecting with SSL, error:14094410: ssl ROUTINES:SSL3_READ_BYTES:SSLV3 alert handshake failure."

`EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError` has nothing to do with HTTP itself, it is an encryption library error. In this case, it is saying the SSL/TLS handshake is failing, before the HTTP request can be sent over the connection. For instance, that could happen if the API requires TLS v1.1+, as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` defaults to TLS v1.0 only, but you can manually enable TLS v1.1 and v1.2 in the SSLIOHandler's `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property.

Also, the post stream is the wrong place to send an HTTP `Authorization` header.

Try this:

```
procedure TOnLineSettingsForm.Button5Click(Sender : TObject);
var
  S: TStringStream;
  sResponse : String;
begin
  if edCert.GetTextLen > 0 then
  begin
    try
      S := TStringStream.Create('...', TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
        IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
        IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := edCert.Text;
        sResponse := IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.cloudwaitress.com/V1/...', S);
      finally
        S.Free;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage('Error.... ' + e.ClassName + ' ' + e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    Beep;
    Beep;
    ShowMessage('Please enter the id code.');
  end;
end;
```

> the Indy version is 10.6.1.5182... Indy 10.6.2 fixed that problem. Could it be I need to get a more recent version of Indy?

Whether it fixes the problem or not, 10.6.1 is very old, so you should upgrade anyway. At the time of this writing, the current version is 10.6.2.5518.

Comment: Remy - thanks for that.  I looked up what is involved in updating Indy on XE7.  Unfortunately, and as you said on another thread - it breacks the Live Tile components.  Which, unfortunately, I had had to used for a couple of crucial forms.  I have XE10.2 and will be migrating everything to that in the next while.  I tried your code.  I now get a similar error - only it now reads "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO"

Comment: I checked the SSL status using this https://foundeo.com/products/iis-weak-ssl-ciphers/test.cfm?test_domain=api.cloudwaitress.com.  For some reason all attempts timed out. Even though pinging the URL results in replies.  However the responses indicated that TSL1.1 and 1.2 were enabled

Comment: I've noticed the IOHandler.SSLOptions.Method keeps defaulting to sslvSSLv23.  Should I override that?

Comment: @AlanJeffery "*I've noticed the IOHandler.SSLOptions.Method keeps defaulting to sslvSSLv23. Should I override that?*" - no, that is expected behavior. SSLv23 is a wildcard that enables dynamic negotiation of multiple SSL/TLS versions

Comment: Remy.  Any idea why that error would occur?  It appears to be attempting to negotiate a connection.  But failing.

Comment: @AlanJeffery not without seeing the complete error message

Comment: Remy.  The full error message is in the first post.  The only difference is the SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO

Comment: Remy.  Sorry.  The error has changed. It is now "EIDOSSUnderlyingcryptoerror with message "Error with SSL error>14077410:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshale failure"  I see the reference to sslv3.  Does that mean we need to use that?

Comment: I tried to use sslv3 - no different.  I've tried to contact the developer of the website in question.  But I'm getting no answers.